# Will fetch_add with relaxed memory order return unique values?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic, memory-model, relaxed-atomics

Imagine N threads running following simple code:

```
int res = num.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

where `num` is:

```
std::atomic<int> num = 0;
```

Is it completelly safe to assume, that `res` for each thread running the code will be different or it is possible that it will be the same for some threads?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. All threads will agree on the order in which the various threads modified the variable `num`; the kth thread to execute that line of code will definitely obtain the value k. The use of `std::memory_order_relaxed`, however, implies that accesses to `num` don't synchronize with each other; thus, for example, one thread may modify some other atomic variable `x` before it modifies `num`, and another thread may see the modification to `num` made by the former thread but subsequently see the old value of `x`.